# Looping through JSON (Foursquare API)

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract data from a JSON file, of which a snippet is below. I want to loop through it to get all categories>name and get , as in this case, "Convenience Store" as a result.

```
{
  'meta': {
    'code': 200,
    'requestId': '5ea184baedbcad001b7a3f8c'
  },
  'response': {
    'venues': [
      {
        'id': '4d03b2f6dc45a093b4b0e5c6',
        'name': 'Ozbesa Market',
        'location': {
          'address': 'Acibadem basogretmen sokak',
          'lat': 41.00622726261631,
          'lng': 29.051791450375678,
          'labeledLatLngs': [
            {
              'label': 'display',
              'lat': 41.00622726261631,
              'lng': 29.051791450375678
            }
          ],
          'distance': 92,
          'cc': 'TR',
          'country': 'Türkiye',
          'formattedAddress': [
            'Acibadem basogretmen sokak',
            'Türkiye'
          ]
        },
        'categories': [
          {
            'id': '4d954b0ea243a5684a65b473',
            'name': 'Convenience Store',
            'pluralName': 'Convenience Stores',
            'shortName': 'Convenience Store',
            'icon': {
              'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/shops/conveniencestore_',
              'suffix': '.png'
            },
            'primary': True
          }
        ],
        'referralId': 'v-1587643627',
        'hasPerk': False
      },
```

Here is my for loop, please help me fix it. It is only returning just convenience stores, but there are also others like 'shopping mall', 'residential building', etc.

```
for ven in json_data:
        for cat in ven:
                print(json_data['response']['venues'][0]['categories'][0]['name'])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You aren't using the things you loop over in those `for` loops at all!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of example, I elided some of the per-venue data and added some categories... but as I mentioned in the comment, you're not using the values you loop over.

```
json_data = {
    "meta": {"code": 200, "requestId": "5ea184baedbcad001b7a3f8c"},
    "response": {
        "venues": [
            {
                "name": "Ozbesa Market",
                "categories": [
                    {"name": "Convenience Store", "primary": True},
                    {"name": "Imaginary Category", "primary": False},
                ],
            },
            {
                "name": "Another Location",
                "categories": [
                    {"name": "Bus Station", "primary": True},
                    {"name": "Fun Fair", "primary": False},
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
}

for venue in json_data["response"]["venues"]:
    print(venue["name"])
    for cat in venue["categories"]:
        print("..", cat["name"])
```

will output e.g.

```
Ozbesa Market
.. Convenience Store
.. Imaginary Category
Another Location
.. Bus Station
.. Fun Fair
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was thinking my loop was close enough.